# How remove focus to the list box?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am having a lisbox where I had set it's property "Selection" to "None".This lisbox is being used in a propertysheet.When I navigate on to the page where list box control is present,here initially when I click on the listbox no selection is happening,this is excepted result.But my only concern is in the lisbox page itself when I use "tab" usually the rectangular dotted line is coming on the Back,Next and Cancel buttons(this is expected),but at the same time after playing with tab around on those buttons,if I had a mouse click on the list box I am getting a rectangular selection on the Item's in the listbox(this is not expected),No selection has to occur.

I even set the "Tab shot" property of the list box  to FALSE.

Can anyone please let me know how can I avoid that rectangular selection on the listbox items,even after using "tab" and having a mouse click on the lisbox that rectangular selection should not happen.

Comment: Can you explain why allowing focus on the listbox is a problem?

Comment: Mark it disabled (either in dialog editor, or programmatically with `EnableWindow`). Then it won't accept focus on mouse click.

Comment: Yes with pleasure,I must populate listbox with some 20 entries .And if the user click on the items in the lisbox none of them should get selected,that rectangular selection should not come.If I disable the window then the scroll bar also getting non-functional.User must able to see what all the entries in the listbox ,but she should not be able select anything just only to let the user understand that there are entries in it.That rectangular selection is coming after using tab on the wizard buttons,and now if I click on the lisbox that selection is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Must be a glitch... If you want to prohibit selections on your listbox without disabling it, what happens if you try

```
void CMyPropertyPage::OnSelchangeList() 
{
    m_list.SetCurSel(-1)
}
```

Comment: Tried but still it is showing that rectangular selection on the items.

Comment: Ok, read again. You mean the focus indicator, which is part of most of the controls, which allows you to navigate between controls via tab. But this is normal behavior. You could replace the SetCurSel(-1) with a SetFocus() to a control created outside of the dialogs visible area to avoid the 'dotted selection' and which is next in the tab order. But you won't be able to navigate with keys and scroll any more.